# Dropwizard specifying external log4j configuration file name

Tags: java-8, dropwizard

As discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/nGF4GFO--YA) from Dropwizard 1.2.4 it is possible to use log4j in place of logback. The steps are also mentioned in the [documentation](http://dropwizard.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual/core.html#logging).

But I am not able to locate how can I specify the log4j file name and location in the configuration file. Can some one let me know how can I specify the log4j configuration file name and its location?

- Dropwizard Version 1.2.4

Comment: https://github.com/arteam/dropwizard-nologback/blob/master/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml This project is referenced in the discussion above. Note that there is big problem with the current approach: https://github.com/arteam/dropwizard-nologback/issues/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the Log4j [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) the log4j file location can be specified using the system property `log4j.configurationFile`.